# SUMIF Similar Text

Tags: excel, text, sumifs

I am trying to use SUMIFS to match either of the following criteria:

"Insurance" or "Motor Insurance"

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B, A:A,{"*Motor Insurance*","*Insurance*"}))
```

A - Insurance, Motor Insurance, Some Insurance

B - 1, 2, 1

The current result is 6 due to my statement matching any string containing "Insurance". Is there a way write a statement where it'll match it the way I would want it to, i.e. if it contains "Motor Insurance" it won't match "Insurance"?

The result should be 4: 2 for "Insurance" and 2 for "Motor Insurance".

Before anyone asks, I can't do a literal match "Motor Insurance" as these three are within a much larger data set where "Insurance" or "Motor Insurance" with be part of that string.

[image: Here is table]

The table above shows that I have three sets of Text and I am trying to get the result of the ones that contain "insurance" and the ones that contain "motor insurance". I understand that one would contain the other but I want the result to be:

"Insurance" is 2 (only matching A2 and A4)

"Motor Insurance" is 2 (only matching A3)

Comment: You might do this by concatenating several CountIfs, such as `= Countif("*Insurance*) - Countif("Moto Insurance")`

Comment: @Variatus Where would I put the count if?

Comment: How should the result be `6`? You show `2` for insurance and `2` for Motor Insurance... Also, how is your data laid out? It's not clear in your post. Is each word in its own cell? Can a cell have both words?

Comment: By definition any cell that contains "Motor insurance" will also contain "Insurance" so why not just sum for the latter, i.e. `=SUMIFS(B:B, A:A,"*Insurance*")`

Comment: @pnuts Sorry, I meant 4

Comment: @barryhoudini because I need separate results unfortunately

Comment: OK, perhaps I don't understand - my suggested formula will give a single result - 4 - you want two separate formulas that will give you 2 each?

Comment: ***How is your data laid out in the spreadsheet*** and what exactly do you want as the output?

Comment: @BruceWayne I've added an image now with a bit more of an explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two separate formulas - one for just "Motor Insurance"

`=SUMIFS(B:B, A:A,"*Motor Insurance*")`

and one for any other Insurance

`=SUMIFS(B:B, A:A,"<>*Motor Insurance*",A:A,"*Insurance*")`

Comment: Just to clarify this answer. For the second part is that:

It will match anything containing "Insurance" other than "Motor Insurance"?